# $session->flash()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP v1.26.
In the default.ctp file, 
I got a single of this code in it:

```
$session->flash();
```

I came a corss a  web site in which the author suggested using this instead:

```
if($session->check('Message.flash')){
$session->flash();
}
```

I do not understand what this line of code is doing:

```
if($session->check('Message.flash')){...}
```

what is "Message.flash" in this case?
Is "Message.flash" a custom variable or 
a built-in varibale which has been predefined in cakePHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Message.flash` is the session variable name. It will be defined by cakephp, when you use `$this->Session->setFlash('Your message');` from your controller.

`if($session->check('Message.flash')){...}` checks, if session `Message.flash`, which contains the flash message,  exists.

Comment: What is the standard usage of Message.flash?

Comment: CakePHP stores your flash message in it.

Answer (score 1):

Note also that contrary to the current manual description, $session->flash() does *not* echo the result, it just returns it, so you will need to have

`echo $session->flash();`

in your view.

Answer (score 0):

For latest cakephp version 
if(!($this->Session->check('Message.flash'))); 
// your code

Comment: He was simply giving an update on the answer for those who stumble on this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In view section for show messages.
$this->Session->flash();
```